# TypeScript Jest: Promise unexpectedly resolving to undefined when it should throw error

Tags: typescript, promise, ts-jest

I'm trying to write unit tests for how this method in a class `FooDataSource` handle errors:

```
export default class FooDataSource extends RESTDataSource {
  const APOLLO_NOT_FOUND_CODE = "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND";
  // ...
  async getFooItems(
    request: GetFooItemsRequest,
    metricsFactory: MetricsFactory
  ): Promise<GetFooItemsResponse> {
    return promiseRetry(RETRY_PARAMS, (retry) =>
      this.get("/", paramsFromRequest(this.clientId, OPERATION_NAME, request), {
        agent: this.agent,
      })
        .then((data) => responseFromDataNotNull(operationName, data))
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.name === NotFoundError.name) {
            throw new ApolloError(error.message, APOLLO_NOT_FOUND_CODE);
          } else {
            metrics.putMetric(RETRY_COUNT_METRIC, 1, Unit.Count);
            return retry(error);
          }
        })
    );
  }
  // ...
}
```

Where `responseFromDataNotNull` is a method I've written in a separate client module to transform the `data` item gotten from the `.get` request into a `GetFooItemsResponse`:

```
// Responses.ts
export class NotFoundError extends Error {
  status: number;

  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "NotFoundError";
    this.status = 404;
  }
}

// Utils.ts
import { NotFoundError, Responses } from "./Responses";

export function responseFromDataNotNull<T extends TypeName>(
  type: T,
  data: any
): Responses[T] {
  if (data.result?.["@type"] === "NotFound.response") {
    throw new NotFoundError("Foo item(s) not found.");
  }
  if (data.result?.["@type"] === `${type}.result`) {
    const { "@type": string, ...response } = data.result;
    return response;
  }
  throw new Error(`Invalid response: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
}
```

The behavior I want out of `getFooItems` is to make the request and try to convert the data to a `GetFooItemsResponse`. This is done in the method `responseFromDataNotNull`. But if `data` has `@type = 'NotFound.response'`, then this process will throw a `NotFoundError`. If a `NotFoundError` is thrown, then `getFooItems` method must stop retrying and throw an `ApolloError` up to the caller of the method. In case of a different kind of error, then retry.

I have deployed this code and confirmed that it throws `ApolloError` when I want it to. But I've struggled to make the following unit test work (`FooDataSource.test.ts`):

```
jest.mock("promise-retry");
describe("FooDataSource - getFooItems", () => {
  let dataSource;
  beforeEach(() => {
    dataSource = new FooDataSource();
  });

  it("should throw ApolloError with code RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND when client throws NotFoundError", async () => {
    const NOT_FOUND_RESPONSE = {
      version: 1.1,
      result: {
        "@type": "NotFound.response",
      },
    };
    jest.spyOn(dataSource, "get").mockResolvedValue(NOT_FOUND_RESPONSE);

    await expect(
      dataSource.getFooItems(
        GET_FOO_ITEMS_REQUEST,
        METRICS_FACTORY
      )
    ).rejects.toThrowError(
      new ApolloError("Foo item(s) not found.", "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND")
    )
  });

  it("should retry when client throws an error other than NotFoundError", async () => {
    const mockError = new Error("Test Error");
    jest.spyOn(dataSource, "get").mockRejectedValue(mockError);
    const retrySpy = jest.fn();

    require("promise-retry").mockImplementation((_, fn) => fn(retrySpy));

    try {
      await dataSource.getFooItems(
        GET_FOO_ITEMS_REQUEST,
        METRICS_FACTORY
      );
    } catch (error) {
      // ignore error
    }

    expect(retrySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockError);
  });
});
```

The second test works, but the first fails with the following error:

```
    expect(received).rejects.toThrowError()

    Received promise resolved instead of rejected
    Resolved to value: undefined

      25 |     jest.spyOn(dataSource, "get").mockResolvedValue(NOT_FOUND_RESPONSE);
      26 |
    > 27 |     await expect(
         |           ^
      28 |       dataSource.getRelatedNewsItemsV2(
      29 |         GET_FOO_ITEMS_REQUEST,
      30 |         METRICS_FACTORY
```

I reemphasize that the source code works -- so I surmise I'm doing something wrong in the unit test.

I also tried `.rejects.toEqual`, `.resolves.toEqual`, `.resolves.toThrowError`. But I still get `undefined`. I also tried replacing

```
jest.spyOn(dataSource, "get").mockResolvedValue(NOT_FOUND_RESPONSE);
```

with

```
jest.spyOn(dataSource, "get").mockRejectedValue(new NotFoundError("..."));
```

But this also runs into the same `undefined` complaint.